# Responsive layout to modify

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm tring to increment the height of the central rectangle

```
<div class="grid_18 alpha mid_container" id="about"></div>
```

but I'm no able with responsive layout and so I can't do this.

```
http://www.casasorgente.it/site_new/
```

Anybody has some ideas?

Comment: The heights seem to work. Also it's not clear what you want as you don't specify the *central rectangle*. Please show what you have tried and post some code. It's really hard to guess...

Comment: I've written the div to increment in height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 390px to a new height in your CSS:

```
#mid_container_wap {
    height: 390px;
}
```

Then change the height of you mid_container from 370px to a new value:

```
.mid_container {
    height: 370px;
}
```